# ElasticEase animation in WPF that stays on center

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I'm trying to make a shake-animation in WPF using the ElasticEase-function. I'd like it to stay on the same position after completed. As it is now, the object I am animating is moving away every time the animation is played.

This is how ElasticEase is working according to WPF:

[image]

But this is what I want (a bit smoother perhaps):

[image]

And this is my current animation:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="1x"
            TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
            TargetName="ScreenContent">
  <DoubleAnimation By="20" Duration="00:00:0.500">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
      <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"
                   Oscillations="3"
                   Springiness="1" />
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: It's moving away because you are animating it `By` 20 units. You may probably set the animation's `From` value instead. However, note that `From` is an absolute value, as opposed to the relative `By`.

Comment: Ahh that easy! Add an answer if you want it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is "moved away" because it is animated using the `DoubleAnimation.By` property. The animation increases the `TranslateTransform.X` value by 20 units each time it is executed.

You may instead start the animation from some value other than the current `TranslateTransform.X` value by setting the `DoubleAnimation.From` property, e.g.:

```
<DoubleAnimation From="20" ...>
```